# Run a java in jar application with JVM parameter

Tags: java, windows, jvm-arguments

I'm developing a Java application. When I try to run the packaged version of application with command:

```
java -Djdk.tls.client.protocols=TLSv1.2 -jar .\target\filesharing-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

I received the following error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: /tls/client/protocols=TLSv1/2
```

I'm using OpenJDK11, and I was thinking the syntax was right. What I'm wrong?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm guessing you're using PowerShell?  Have you tried `java "-Djdk.tls.client.protocols=TLSv1.2" -jar .\target\filesharing-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`?

Comment: Tnx, you solve my problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For future searchers, Powershell requires command line arguments that contain the period (full stop) character to be quoted.  So in this case the command should be:

```
java "-Djdk.tls.client.protocols=TLSv1.2" -jar .\target\filesharing-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Any `-D` type arguments should be wrapped in double quotes.

In case you're not using Powershell but are instead using `cmd` wrap just the value of the `-D` in double quotes:

```
java -Djdk.tls.client.protocols="TLSv1.2" -jar .\target\filesharing-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```